# What is a backslash colon doing in this chown command?

Tags: bash, unix, terminal

What is the `\:` doing in the command below?

```
sudo chown nobody\: folder/
```

Is it some kind of mistake?

Comment: it looks like an escape character for the : . if you were to store the command as a string, perhaps to use it in a script, or xargs, you would have to escape the colon. Some less common shells may prefer it that way. outside a string, most shells would treat it as a multiline continuation statement, which should execute just as well.

Comment: @FrankThomas: I'm not sure _why_ "you'd have to escape the colon"?

Comment: you wouldn't in 99% of cases. sorry if I misspoke. those are just possible cases where you might have to, entirely dependent on the exact case in question. There is certianly no reason it needs to be present in the line presented. I can only imagine why one might do it.

Comment: It's a direct input from terminal. What is the difference between '**nobody:**' and '**nobody**' in this command?

Comment: nothing. chown assumes that if only one operand is provided, that it is the user. `chown :users \` would have meaning, indicating that users is a group, but if you are only changing the owner-user, then there is no need to use the colon at all, though I will say, it makes things nice an unambiguous. http://www.linfo.org/chown.html

Comment: It could be an emoticon  :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\` doesn't make any difference whatsoever, since the shell eliminates that. The `chown` utility will receive a literal `nobody:` as its first argument.

The presense vs. absence of `:` does make a difference, though. See chown's manual page for clear description.

`sudo chown nobody folder/` changes the owner, but leaves the group of the file intact.

`sudo chown nobody: folder/` changes both the owner and the group of the file. The group is set to the `nobody` user's default group, as defined in `/etc/passwd` or some other mechanism (e.g. ldap).

Comment: `chown` includes `chgrp`.

Answer (score 2):

The backslash (\) is making sure that the shell does not interpret the following character as a [shell meta-character](http://faculty.salina.k-state.edu/tim/unix_sg/shell/metachar.html).  Since the colon is *not* such a character, the backslash is effectively doing nothing.

The colon (:) is used to separate "user" from "group" -- the `chown` command changes both *user* and *group* ownership.  With no group specified, the colon is not necessary and so is effectively doing nothing.

Answer (score 2):

**What:**

It is called [character escaping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character), and it ensures that the colon is literally treated as such.

**Why:**

In the shell, a colon can be used to separate filename from hostname (commonly used with commands such as `rsync` and `scp`). In chown it is used for separating user from group.

The shell reads the command first, and to ensure that the colon isn't treated as the special character it is, but instead part of the arguement sent to chown, it is escaped with the backslash.

It should be noted that in this particular case I do not see a need for having the colon there at all, as having the group specified, let alone a blank group name, is not required with chown.

**How:**

Prefixing a character with a backslash is common, and can be used for many others that the shell would otherwise treat differently. For example:

`ls test*` will list all files beginning with test
`ls test\*` will list a file named `test*` with the asterisk as a part of the actual filename.

---

Sometimes, the escape character can be used the other way around for cases when you want a normal character to be treated specially. Examples include:

- `\n` a newline
- `\t` a tab character

Answer (score 0):

Backslash is [an escape character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) which modifies the interpretation of the special characters. However colon is not a special character for shell interpreter (such as `bash`), so it actually doing nothing.

Colon character in `chown`/`chmod` is used to distinguish user and group name (when group operand is specified). Previous versions of the chown utility used the dot, but it was changed to be a colon, as user and group names may contain the dot character.